# What happens when you copy a hardlink?

Tags: cp, hard-link

Imagine I have a file `something/a.txt`, which I hardlink from `b.txt`. Now, if I `cp b.txt c.txt`, is `c.txt` a hard link to `a.txt`, or is it a copy of the contents of `a.txt`?

Comment: The latter (a copy of the contents, etc).

Comment: Remember hardlink is simply another name of the same inode, it IS that inode, not a link to that inode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hardlinks are a completely different concept from other kinds of links or references.

A hardlink is another name to the same inode (a bit simplified: the file contents and metadata).

E.g. if you hardlink `a.txt` from `b.txt`, both names `a.txt` and `b.txt` are equal names to the same file. After hardlinking you cannot distinguish anymore if `a.txt` or `b.txt` was the original file name. Both names point to the same file.

That means `cp b.txt c.txt` will copy the file contents exactly as if you did `cp a.txt c.txt`.