# How to effectively trace hardlink in Linux?

Tags: find, inode, hard-link

Softlinks are easily traceable to the original file with `readlink` etc...  but I am having a hard time tracing hardlinks to the original file.

```
$ ll -i /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash  
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /bin/bash*  
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /usr/bin/bash*
                   ^
```

above is as expected - cool --> both files point to same inode 1310813
(but the number of links, indicated by `^`, shows to be 1. From Gilles answer the reason for this can be understood)

```
$ find / -samefile /bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

above is as expected - so no problems.

```
$ find / -samefile /usr/bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

above is **NOT** cool. How do I trace the original file or **every hardlink** using the `/usr/bin/bash` file as reference?

Strange - below did not help either.

```
$ find / -inum 1310813 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: File system designs tend to make it simple to map a path to an inode; that's the primary purpose of a file system. The other direction, though, typically isn't tracked. The only real way to find all paths that map to a given inode is to check all candidate paths.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, you don't actually have a hardlink here. Assuming you have GNU readlink (which you should on Linux, but not necessarily on other *nix platforms), note that `readlink -f` will fully canonicalize a path... which, in this instance, would reveal that the canonical path of `/bin/bash` is indeed `/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Matthew but that doesn’t help with the problem the OP is ultimately trying to solve, [finding the package which owns `/usr/bin/bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607504/86440) (which is installed as `/bin/bash`). The canonical location from `readlink`’s perspective doesn’t match the canonical location from the package manager’s perspective. That’s why the OP is looking for links *to* `/usr/bin/bash`, not what `/bin/bash` links to.

Comment: @StephenKitt, that sounds like a package manager problem. `rpm` identifies `bash-5.0.17-1.fc32.x86_64` as the owner of _both_ `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash`. Anyway, I don't see that information in the question, so expecting me to be aware of it isn't very reasonable.

Comment: @Matthew I’m not expecting anything, I’m only explaining the context (because it’s not apparent in the question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when you copy a hardlink?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517494/what-happens-when-you-copy-a-hardlink)

Comment: @cgg909, the question pointed by you is not related to this. I will appreciate if you can delete the comment as it will not distract others

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First, there is no original file in the case of hard links; all hard links are equal.

However, hard links aren’t involved here, as indicated by the link count of 1 in `ls -l`’s output:

> ```
> $ ll -i /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash  
> 1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /bin/bash*  
> 1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /usr/bin/bash*
> ```

Your problem arises because of a symlink, the `bin` symlink which points to `usr/bin`. To find [all the paths in which `bash` is available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607504/86440), you need to tell `find` to follow symlinks, using the `-L` option:

```
$ find -L / -xdev -samefile /usr/bin/bash 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/bash
```

I’m using `-xdev` here because I know your system is installed on a single file system; this avoids descending into `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys` etc.

Comment: There is no additional hard link here.

Comment: As far as I can tell my answer doesn’t say it’s a hard link. The OP is looking for the paths at which a given binary is installed (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607504/86440) for context); because of the `/usr` merge, `bash` is installed as `/bin/bash` but also shows up as `/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you can tell there's no hardlink because the link-count is `1`.  That's how you know it must be something else.

Answer (score 25):

> how do I trace the original file or every hardlink using /usr/bin/bash file as reference

With GNU find (or any other version of `find` that has the `-samefile` option), and assuming that `/usr/bin/bash` is located on the `/` filesystem, this is correct:

```
find / -xdev -samefile /bin/bash
```

Use `-xdev` since hard links can't cross filesystem boundaries. Do not redirect errors: if you don't have permission to traverse a directory, a hard link could be present under that directory and you'd miss it.

The mistake you're making is that you're looking for another hard link that doesn't exist. You actually have the information to know that it doesn't exist:

```
1310813 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1183448 Jun 18 21:14 /bin/bash*
                   ^
```

The hard link count of `/bin/bash` is 1.

There is a single file in `/` which is the same as `/usr/bin/bash`. The file `/bin/bash` is the same as `/usr/bin/bash` for a different reason: the *directories* `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are the same file. Since `find / -samefile /bin/bash` points to `/usr/bin/bash`, `/bin` has a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`. More precisely, from the information in the question, and assuming that `/bin` is not a directory hard link (a poorly supported, rarely used feature), we know that `/bin` is a symbolic link which resolves to `/usr/bin`; it could be a symbolic link to another symbolic link and so on eventually resolving to `/usr/bin` or to some equivalent path such as `///////usr/bin/`, but most likely it's a symbolic link whose target is `/usr/bin`.

Looking for all symbolic links to a file on the whole system is not particularly productive. For example, on Linux, there's a file `/proc/*/exe` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/bash` (or `/bin/bash`) for every process that's running bash. And if you look for symbolic links to a directory, you'll end up inside infinite recursion, for example with `/proc/*/root` pointing to `/` (except for chrooted processes).

If you need to know whether two paths point to the same file, on Linux, you can use either of

```
[ /bin/bash -ef /usr/bin/bash ]
test /bin/bash -ef /usr/bin/bash
```

(`-ef` isn't POSIX but it's in dash, bash, BusyBox and GNU coreutils). If you need to get a canonical path to a file, in the sense that distinct files always have distinct canonical names, you can use

```
readlink -f /bin/bash
```

(This can miss files that are equal via mounted directories, for example if the same network location is mounted in two different ways.)

Comment: @gilles-so-stop-being-evil, @Stephen-Kitt, -  less related Q, but `The hard link count of /bin/bash is 1.`, what does `ls -l` third column mean for dirs. If I got it right, it means the number of dir entries within the listed dir. So is not that quite different for `files` and `directories`

Comment: @samshers https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to